# How to unregister sidebar for template_part?

Tags: sidebar, get-template-part

Can you help me please?

I have this code in my index.php:

```
php get_sidebar();
```

And I have a template_part 'loop-fullwidth',
which I call in index.php.

I need to register sidebar for index.php and
unregister sidebar for a 'loop-fullwidth'.

Can't do it. Tried to write in index.php code like 
this:

```
php if(!is_singular('partials/loop', 'fullwidth'));
  get_sidebar();
else if:
  unregister_sidebar();
```

But it didn't help.

I just start to learn php, can't figure out how to solve
this.

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: *I need to register sidebar for index.php and unregister sidebar for a 'loop-fullwidth'*. This does not make sense. What are you trying to do. Do you need to have this sidebar only in index.php?

Comment: Please do not cross post. Choose one platform and stick with it. Thank you for understanding